# MySQL. Репликация двух баз данных построчно

Tags: mysql, синхронизация, репликация

Необходимо писать данные в базу MySQL. Потеря даже одной записи критична. С базой будут работать не более 10 человек. Нагрузка минимальная. Навыки в MySQL начального уровня, буду рад ссылкам и направлениям, в какую сторону копать.

1. Возможно ли установить 2 базы MySQL на одном компьютере на на разных жестких дисках? (Думаю, что не проблема, главное разобраться в настройках)
2. Можно ли 2 базы MySQL настроить так, что бы писать в одну, данные сразу же применялись во вторую. При этом, если по какой либо причине вторая база не смогла совершить запись, получить ошибку и не писать данные в первую базу (например, если из строя выйдет жесткий диск).

Т.е. сейчас есть 1 база данных MySQL, необходимо сделать репликацию во вторую базу данных так, что бы, гарантированно запись пишется либо в обе базы, либо не в одну (в этом случае необходимо получить ошибку).

P.S. Самый главный критерий, исключить ситуацию, когда в первую базу запись успешна, а во вторую не прошла.

Comment: Если потеря данных критична, то располагать вторую БД на той же машине нельзя. Бывали случаи в практике, когда горел блок питания и выжигал все диски заодно. Так что кластер стоит собирать не менее чем из 2х машин, желательно находящихся в разных помещениях. И поднимать между ними репликацию. По поводу самой репликации просто наберите в гугле "mysql репликация" и найдете много хороших статей с настройками (а не ту, что дали выше). И при настройках стоит как следует поэкспериментировать, что бы знать как вести себя при отказах. Если интересна master-master репликация, то смотреть galera cluster

Comment: @Mike не все так серьезно :) весь учет все равно хранится в том же помещении, только в бумажном варианте. Спасибо, обращу внимание на блок питания. Две машины подумаем, накладно. Да и описанная выше вероятность с блоком питания мне кажется настолько маловероятна, что можно пренебречь, но! Спасет ли ситуацию usb внешний жесткий диск?

Comment: Евгений, Вы явно стараетесь сделать из дерьма масло. Но поверьте, мазаться оно будет, а вонять не перестанет. @Mike Вам ещё озвучил достаточно щадящий вариант, для Ваших требований чуть ли не начального уровня, в котором ещё урезать - нечего.

Comment: @Akina я пытаюсь сделать из бумаги рабочую автоматизацию элементарного учета на 3-4 таблицы. Предложенный 1C (денег не жалко) решает проблемы, но создает новые. Бизнесу нужно элементарное простое решение решающие лишь задачу прихода и возврата. Опыт позволяет написать UI, логику и БД. Одна проблема, быть уверенным что какой то непредвиденный случай не похоронит данные. Сейчас все ведется в двух тетрадях вручную. Пожары потопы и т.д. меня не волнуют, а вот выход из строя HDD очень даже. Ну и блок питания, буду искать информацию о рисках. 100% надежности никто в мире не гарантирует :)

Comment: Настройте для начала бекапы (https://serveradmin.ru/polnyj-i-inkrementnyj-backup-mysql/) на место в каком нибудь облачном хранилище. Хранилки копейки стоят. Например холодное хранилище в yandex object storage 67 копеек / гигабайт в месяц. Бухгалтеры при наличии бумажных документов вполне могут восстановить 1 день данных в ручную. А инкрементальные бекапы можно и несколько раз в день делать. Ну или возьмите готовый mysql в облаке, он конечно подороже, от 500р/мес. И используйте его в качестве слейва репликации и будет вам онлайн бекап запись в запись.

Comment: Кстати репликация не отменяет необходимости бекапов базы, ведь проблемы могут быть не только с физическим диском, а программные, типа случайно удалил не ту таблицу и это удаление на реплику то же ушло ...

Comment: А в случае одной машины второй mysql вообще ни к чему. Поставьте все и систему и mysql на рейд зеркало из 2х дисков. Полная безопасность от отказа одного диска. И скорость чтения в 2 раза выше. (только надо настроить еще и мониторинг, а то отказ одного диска можно год не замечать, система то работать продолжит. Пока второй из строя не выйдет)

Comment: @Mike на трех точках интернета нет в зданиях, ставить gsm модемы доп. расходы. В перспективе большие на каждую точку. Вопрос не "Как реализовать бэкапы", а "Как реализовать бэкапы на два HDD", остальное мои проблемы и головная боль :) Правда, я описал тех. задание, а описывать бизнес процессы - площадка не та, да и бизнес то маленький. Розница на 3 точки, по упрощенке, бух. учет не нужен, Казахстан. Нужно только сохранить данные, которые я пишу. Сохранить от сбоев железа, не от пожара, потопа, урагана. Облака тоже были рассмотрены, но отброшены из за доп. расходов.

Comment: @Mike программные сбои это тоже лично моя головная боль, а рейд слишком сложный момент для копеечной реализации. Да и из за нехватки знаний о рейдах, не понимаю как  MySQL может дублироваться в рейде. Этот вариант крайний, если не найдется более простых и надежных решений.

Comment: Рейд как раз самое простое решение при наличии двух дисков. И БД тут не причем, полную синхронность данных на дисках обеспечивает операционная система (или вообще контроллер на материнской плате). И главное, дублируется не только БД, но и вся система в целом. Выход из строя одного диска проходит не замеченным, сервер продолжает работать как ни в чем ни бывало